# Reading files per character with Lua (Löve API)

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to read files per character in Lua with the Löve API but I just can't figure out how. There must be some way to do this right? In other posts I found something about reading files per line but I really need to read them per char. Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Leveljaap

Comment: It's very slow. Read whole file if you have enough memory and get that characters through `gmatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `f` is a file handle, then `f:read(1)` returns the next byte in the file or nil at the end of the file.

Note that the next *byte* may not be the next *character* if the file contains UTF-8 Unicode for instance.